# Is there any solution for fixing this WEBRTC error

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

```
const socket = io('/');
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid');
const myVideo = document.createElement('video');
myVideo.muted = true;
var peer = new Peer(undefined,{
    path: '/peerjs',
    host: '/',
    port:'3030'
}); 
let myVideoStream
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({     
    video:true ,
    audio:true
  }).then(stream => {
    myVideoStream = stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo,stream);
   
    peer.on('call',call =>{
        call.answer(stream)
        const video = document.createElement('video')
        call.on('stream',userVideoStream => {
            addVideoStream(video,userVideoStream)
        })
    })
    
})

 peer.on('open',id => {
    socket.emit('join-room',ROOM_ID ,id);
 });
 

 socket.on('user-connected',(userId)=>{
        connectToNewUser(userId,stream);
 })
 
 const connectToNewUser = (userId , stream)=>{
    const call = peer.call(userId, stream)
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
      addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
    })
 }


const addVideoStream = (video,stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',()=>{
        video.play();
    })
    videoGrid.append(video);
}
```

I am basically trying to make a zoom clone and I have created this script.js code where I will  send the URL to another guy he will open the URL and an id will be created which will let me and my friend connect on video call.
I have used the below code in ejs file.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"</script>
```

But I am getting error which I am unable to fix. Please help me out. Errors are as follows:

Error : DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://unpkg.com/peerjs.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Error : websocket.js:87 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3030/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=wp9ly7xzJ7WSu3WmAAAA' failed: Invalid frame header

Comment: The link https://unpkg.com/peerjs.min.js.map is broken, check the response. But do you have your peerjs server running? And running on port 3030? https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server

Comment: can you able to view your friend's video?

Comment: @Vishy No i am not able to view. Its giving me the error as mentioned

Comment: @Daantje How to check my peerjs server is running or not. I mean I have imported and implemented call from peerjs but still not able to figure out

Comment: You need to start the server, that will work as an connection broker between the client apps. See the peerjs-server readme: https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server#natively